# How to Store and Retrieve Dynamic Table using Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a dynamic table using Asp.net with c#. Now I want to store this dynamically created table in the session, How can i do that?

I am new to Asp.Net and Programming aswell.

Thanks.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

public void CreateRuntime_Table()
{
    int tblRows = int.Parse(txtrow.Text);
    int tblCols = int.Parse(txtcol.Text);

    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.BorderWidth = 3;
    tbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    tbl.ID = "myTable";

    for (int i = 1; i <= tblRows; i++)
    {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 1; j <= tblCols; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            txtbox.Text = "Test Row:" + i + "Test Col:" + " " + j;
            //Add the control to the table cell
            tc.Controls.Add(txtbox);
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    form1.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateRuntime_Table();
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, if you have the choice then skip WebForms (aspx) and DataTables and start teaching yourself MVC and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the table in a session do:

```
Table tbl = new Table();
...
Session["myTable"] = tbl;
```

The to get the table from the session do:

```
Table getTableFromSession = (Table)Session["myTable"];
```